# Javascript decrement number in string

Tags: javascript

How do I decrement a number in a string? Right now I've got this:

```
var existingId = "test 10 test";

let newId = existingId .replace(/\d+/g, function(match, number) {
       return parseInt(number)-1;
});
```

The number is not always in the same place. I cannot store the number in a variable.

But my regex is not correct.

Comment: .split(' ') and .join('') will help you

Comment: yes it is, but your arguments are not. your `number` IS your whole `match`. The arguments for the function are (match, ...groups, index, inputString). Since you have no groups in your regex, your argument `number` contains the `index`

Comment: It looks acceptable way from my point of view

Comment: The best way to do it will depend on a number of things. Is the number always in the same place in the string? Can the string have multiple numbers? Is there a reason you can't store the number in a variable and produce the string through concatenation if and when it's needed?

Comment: @Jonah good questions will update my answer.

Comment: try`var s = "test 10 test";

s = s.replace(/\d+/g, function(m){
    return parseInt(m, 10) - 1;
});`  demo http://jsfiddle.net/6YJQx/

Comment: Is `"test 9 test"` the expected result?

Comment: @Edison even the `parseInt` is obsolete: `inputString.replace(/-?\d+/g, number => number-1)`

Answer (score 4):

You almost got it

```
var existingId = "test 10 test";

let newId = existingId.replace(/\d+/g, function(match) {
    return parseInt(match) - 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use **match** argument instead number

```
let newId = existingId.replace(/\d+/g, function (match, number) {
                return parseInt(match) - 1;
);
```